# Finding the width of a smaller rectangle

Tags: area

We have a large rectangle, with a width of 14m and a length of 9m. In the middle of this rectangle is a smaller one, with a length given of 5m. The text prompts me to use the width of the larger rectangle, subtract a certain number from it to supposedly get the width. How would i solve this? Or what number would i use?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. What, exactly, do you wish to solve for? There is not enough information provided to solve for the width of the smaller rectangle. Were you given more information about the smaller rectangle?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are solving for.  The width of the smaller triangle?  The area of the smaller triangle? Does the smaller triangle have the same width as the larger one but is only shorter?  Do you have the area of the smaller and you want to find the width?  Is the smaller rectangle share edges and only shorter and you want to find the area?  .... It isn't clear what you question actually *is*.

Comment: ... or are the two rectangles proportional?

Comment: @fleablood: That's a good guess, but it's somewhat at odds with the word "subtract."  Still, it's not hard to see a bit of confusion explain that away...

Comment: "That's a good guess"  What's a good guess?.... " Still, it's not hard to see a bit of confusion explain that away"  ... Is that a run-on sentence?  What are you saying?... um, are you aware that I honestly *don't* have any idea what the OPs question actually is and I'm asking him/her to clarify and figure out what it is?  I'm not leading her/him along or dropping hints.  I am saying upfront and outright "Your question doesn't make any sense and I don't know what you are asking".